# How to run an activity in the background in android, and it should show up if a message is recieved?

Tags: android, background, sms

I have a requirment in my task that there is a activity that recieves a text sms and performs some functionality, i want that activity to sleep in the background until an sms is recieved, and when that sms is recieved it should pop up and perform the functionality

1. How can i make the application work and listen in the background in android?
2. How can i activate it upon reception of the message? and how to test it on emulator?

Regards,

Wasif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this post on howto emulate, receive and handle SMS messages

[Android API – SMS handling](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/)

Comment: yes this is something i have already done my activity currently receives and processes the sms but i want it to be running in the background and activate it if sms received!!!

Comment: Can you give me reason, why you want to have an activity running in background and just activate it?

Comment: i have an activity that gets activated on the reception of message. i am more clear now that if i implement a broadcast listener the application gets registered in the android OS and is in listening mode always when the phone gets started. is it so?

Comment: Yes you are right. But note that some broadcasts cannot be cought if your application is on SD card.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement it as a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: can you please give me more details about it will my activity be a service and how should be done? and what about the sms part?